# Excel Data Connection to Active Directory

Tags: excel, vba, active-directory, connection-string

I want to create a data connection in [excel-2007](/questions/tagged/excel-2007) that pulls the result of an [active-directory](/questions/tagged/active-directory) query into a sheet in my workbook.

I see that I [can do this](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/11/01/query-active-directory-from-excel) with VBA but I agree with Rob [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/561218-data-connection-active-directory.html) that it should be easier than that, just using "OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services"

A bit of googling suggests that this is a hole in our collective knowledge that deserves to be filled!

Comment: It's not that complex - not sure what the problem is here: don't forget you're posting this on a *programming* site...  The example code you linked to could be simplified (ie. you don't need an explicit Command object), but it's quite manageable.

Comment: Oops!  Good point, Tim.  I hang out here so much I forgot. :)

Comment: Re-asked this question at http://superuser.com/q/340187/53184

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours trial & error, I gave up and did the AD stuff on the SQL-side, using

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyActiveDirectoryLinkedServer, 'SELECT ... FROM ''LDAP://...'' WHERE ...')
```

But this requires a linked server to be set up, which is against DBA best practice.  Luckily in my case I had one already.  ;)

Comment: I'm still interested in a proper Excel-side fix if anyone has one.  Hopefully someone at SuperUser will help: http://superuser.com/questions/340187/excel-data-connection-to-active-directory